# What does the source limit in CodeChef mean?

Tags: size

In a practise problem given on [CodeChef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeChef), the source limit is written under the problem. What does it mean?

PS: If I allocate an array of size 1000 X 1000 and the source limit is 50,000 Bytes, then am I not violating the source limits?

Comment: Be sure to mark the correct answer for future readers please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *source limit* is the maximum size of the source code; not the memory allocated by the JVM during *runtime*, so no. You would not be violating the source limits. Read [here](http://blog.codechef.com/2009/02/25/codechef-tutorial-your-first-non-trivial-problem/) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for the source limit.

However, to thwart lazy coders like me, the problem setter has set a *code* size limit which is “Source limit”. So your program’s source code must be at most 2000 *bytes* - CodeChef *link* above.